# Passing an Array through a Method

Tags: javascript, arrays, parameter-passing

Ive done lots of debugging but it seems that the error happens with I try to use "this" in `ae2Multi()`.

```
<html><head>
<title>Custom</title>
<style type="text/css"></style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ae2(elementName) {
        var elementObject;
        var elementType = elementName.charAt(0);

        if(elementType == "#") {
            elementObject = document.getElementById(elementName.substr(1));
        } else if(elementType == ".") {
            elementObject = document.getElementsByClassName(elementName.substr(1));
        } else {
            elementObject = document.getElementsByTagName(elementName);
        }
        return elementObject;
    }

    function ae2Single() {
        this.innerHTML = "singleIsWorking";
    }

    function ae2Multi() {
        alert(this);
        for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
            this[i].innerHTML = "it really worked!";
        }
    }

    Element.prototype.ae2Single = ae2Single;
    Element.prototype.ae2Multi = ae2Multi;

    window.onload = function() {
        ae2(".container").ae2Multi();
    }
</script></head><body><div id="containerMain">hello world!</div><div class="container">hello again!</div><div class="container">hello yet again!</div></body</html>
```

Comment: what client side library are you using? mootools?

Comment: "the error happens" - what error?

Comment: None, that was a file I linked to with my javascript, I just put to code inline to make it easier to post and forget to take out the reference.

Comment: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'ae2(".container").ae2Multi()')

Answer (score 2):

When you select multiple elements you get back a `NodeList`, not an `Element`. So you need to edit the `NodeList` prototype:

```
Element.prototype.ae2Single = ae2Single;
NodeList.prototype.ae2Multi = ae2Multi;
```

`getElementById` is the only one that returns an `Element` it seems, while the rest return a `NodeList`.

Comment: Is there anyway to write 1 function to do both?

Comment: What if I have it put the element that getElementById returns into a node list by itself. Would that work?

Comment: I don't see why you need to augment the prototypes of NodeList or Element - this is not clever. Why can't you just handle what you're doing inside of your first function instead returning the element?

Comment: @AaronEllington You may use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) instead, it will always return a `NodeList`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't augment the prototypes of native objects even if someone is threatening to cut off your hand unless you do so.

EDIT: Providing this answer because you asked "Is there anyway to write 1 function to do both"

```
function ae2(elementName) {
    var elementObject;
    var elementType = elementName.charAt(0);

    if(elementType == "#") {
        elementObject = document.getElementById(elementName.substr(1));
    } else if(elementType == ".") {
        elementObject = document.getElementsByClassName(elementName.substr(1));
    } else {
        elementObject = document.getElementsByTagName(elementName);
    }

    if(elementObject.length === 1){
        //ae2Single
        elementObject.innerHTML = "singleIsWorking";
    }
    else if(elementObject.length > 1){
        //ae2Multi
        for (var i = 0; i < elementObject.length; i++) {
            elementObject[i].innerHTML = "it really worked!";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, but why? http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8